# How to calculate Delta in Python? Preparation for a Python course

Tags: python

Please do not close this thread, because I don't know how to ask for assistance with this problem. :(
I have a few assignments to do before I start a Python course. I would need an answer as to how to add DELTA into the equation. My code doesn't work and I surmise that it has something to do with Delta implementation. I am not good at math and cannot gauge how to add it.
My task is the following:

Quadratic equations
Write a program in the file that helps middle school students count the roots of quadratic equations.
The program should:

1. display a message on the screen:

`Formula in the form: a*x**2 + b*x + c == 0`

2. display the message on the screen : "Specify an A:".
3. retrieve the value from the user and store it in the variable A (remember to transfer the value to the appropriate type),
4. display the message on the screen : "Specify B:",
5. get the value from the user and store it in the variable B (remember to transfer the value to the corresponding type),
6. display the message on the screen: "Specify C:",
7. receive the value from the user and store it in variable C (remember to transfer the value to the correct type),
8. count the delta,
   If delta > 0, count the values of x_1 and x_2 from the formula:

   x_1 = (-b - delta**0.5) / (2 * a)
   x_2 = (-b + delta**0.5) / (2 * a)

and display it as the following:

```
Square root of the quadratic equation or prime numbers of the quadratic equation:
x_1 = <value>
x_2 = <value>
```

if delta = 0, count the values of x_1 and x_2 and then display them on the screen in the form:

```
The primes of the quadratic equation/square root of the quadratic equation:
x_1 = x_2 = <value>.
```

If the delta is negative, " No solutions" will be displayed on the screen.

Note: We assume that the user entered the numbers a, b and c correctly.
Note 2 : Here the delta is not a mutation of coronavirus. :D

My code:

```
a= float(input("Enter A "))
b= float(input("Enter B:  "))
c= float(input("Enter C: "))
x1 = (-b - delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
x2 = (-b + delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
print("The equation in the form:")
print("a*x**2 + b*x + c == 0")

if delta > 0:
    print(f'''The primes of the quadratic equation/square root of the quadratic equation:
x_1 = {x1}, x_2 = {x2}''')
elif delta == 0:
    print(f'''The primes of the quadratic equation/square root of the quadratic equation:
x1 = x2 = {x2} ''')
else:
    print("No results")
```

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean your code throws an exception saying that delta is not defined? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should add an a line like below to calculate delta.

```py
          ...
c= float(input("Enter C: "))
delta = (b**2) - (4*a*c)  
x1 = (-b - delta ** 0.5) / (2 * a)
          ...
```